# How to make a switch from one view to the same view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm creating a questionnaire app for iOS in Swift.
I only need one view for all questions. How do I make one generic view and make it look like I'm switching to the new view with swipe when only replacing some of the data on that view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I think I know what you're attempting to do. You could possibly do it like this. This is assuming you have a custom UIViewController subclass with all your textfields and labels on it; I've named this `QuestionaireViewController`.

```
let nextVC = QuestionaireViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

Additionally, you'll want to set up unwind segues each time you create a new VC, so that if needed the Navigation Controller can segue back.

Comment: Can I do a segue to the same view? The reason I need to do it is I want to let user create questionnaires himself and keep the data in coredata. I don't want to create a new view controller per each question.

Comment: And I'm not doing the whole app within a single ViewController. I just want one generic ViewController for all questions (a couple text fields + image).

Comment: That's good, thanks. But it's more of a workaround rather than a solution. I'm sure there should be a way to make switch from one UIViewController to itself.

Comment: Well what you want is to go from one UIViewController to **another** UIViewController *of the same type*. You don't want to literally transition from a VC to itself; that's not possible (you're not going anywhere in that scenario). If you want to do this the right way without workarounds, you should use segues, and for each question page, push a new VC (of the same type) onto the stack.

Comment: So you're suggesting dynamic creation of a new VC for each question? At what moment should I be doing it? And could you give me a little code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an animation to your subviews (UILabels, etc.) on screen. You can add a separate animation to each swipe gesture and have the animation move in the direction of the swipe. I like this because you have some flexibility in what you animate and how you do so.

You'll need to setup swipe gesture recognizers and methods for each to handle the swipe and animate the layers.

If you want a "traditional feeling" swipe left / swipe right type of setup you'll need to setup a push animation with a subtype for each direction.